# How to add an input string widget to an event template in Plone

Tags: python, plone

I wish to add custom input field attributes to the default event page template (or rather extend it). I don't know which is the template for the same and where is it located in ZMI.

F.e. I wish to add custom metadata like client name, lawyer name etc. I know how to add the metadata for the same but how to extend the event's default template.

Other option: If I use ploneformgen for the same, how can I get the calendar view for the events created? Finally wish to have calendar view for the custom data input with the start and end date for input created, which is searchable. The data for the collection should be searchable and should have 'hyperlinks to the folders' containing the related documents in the tabular view?

I am using `zettwerk.fullcalendar` for plone 4.1

Answer (score 1):

To add extra fields to the existing Event type, using http://pypi.python.org/pypi/archetypes.schemaextender

It's not something you can do TTW.

Answer (score 0):

Found the template at /site/portal_skins/event_view which you can customize. At least know where to start with. But when I use the customize tab, I get the error for the python expression witout changing the code as :

> Macro expansion failed : widget
>   On testing, it shows error with the python expression:
>   Module Products.PageTemplates.ZRPythonExpr, line 48, in **call**
>   __traceback_info__: context.start().Date() == context.end().Date()
>   Module PythonExpr, line 1, in 
>   The template code is :

```
<tal:differentday tal:condition="python:context.start().Date() == context.end().Date()"
                                              i18n:translate="event_when_differentday">
```

Can anyone guide as to what the error in the above expression is?